# Remove JSON comments scrapy

Tags: python, json, scrapy

The field i'm trying to get on the page is this:

```
<script data-test-gtm-script>
// Fill GtmDataLayer with data
gtmDataLayer = window.gtmDataLayer || [];
gtmDataLayer.push({
        'userId' : '5a96c0b1-1caf-4fb3-8272-c94a1796f6ec',
        'isAnonymous' : 'true',
        'language' : 'nl',
        'seriousness' : '0|false',
        'pagetype' : 'object',
        'allowPersonalisatie' : 'true',
        'allowAdvertenties' : 'true',
        'allowAnalytisch' : 'true',
        'allowFunctioneel' : 'true',
        'explicitAcceptOfCookies' : 'true',
        'makelaarVestigingnummer' : '62303',
        'makelaarsvereniging' : 'Vbo',
        'brochure' : 'True',
        'foto360' : 'False',
        'plattegrond' : 'True',
        'toppositie' : 'False',
        'video' : 'True',
        'promolabel' : 'False',
        'inbeeld' : 'False',
        'veiling' : 'False',
        'veilingproduct' : 'False',
        'openhuizendagpromotiepakket' : 'False',
        'soortaanbod' : 'koop',
        'objectType' : 'Woonhuis',
        'soortObject' : 'Eengezinswoning | hoekwoning',
        'aangebodensinds' : 'Vandaag',
        'koopprijs' : '300000',
        'aantalfotos' : '35',
        'globalId' : '5827539',
        'soortPlaatsing' : 'Basis',
        'plaats' : 'Enschede',
        'postcode' : '7534MN',
        'provincie' : 'Overijssel',
        'flex' : 'False',
        'functie_context' : 'koop',
});

// Initialize Google Tag Manager
(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
        'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
    }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
        '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
})(window, document, 'script', 'gtmDataLayer', 'GTM-NPB6HG');
```

The problem is that I can't convert this to JSON because of the comments. How do I properly get the values? The specific value I need is `aangebodensinds`.

What I've tried:

```
items = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'aangebodensinds')]/text()").get().replace('\r\n','').strip()
```

But when I try this to convert this to JSON it fails with errors.

Comment: hey! what errors are you getting trying to convert the json? 
also, can you print the content of `items`?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html#handling-different-response-formats

Answer (score 1):

The content of the script tag you are getting correctly, `items` contains the whole JS code inside the tag.

So now you just need to extract an object from the js code, you can use regex like this:

```
items = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'aangebodensinds')]/text()").\
    re(r'gtmDataLayer\.push\(({[^}]*})')[0]
```

now `items` will contain parsable JSON string.

Here is an alternative answer using the `js2xml` which is also a good solution I think [Scrapy parse javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662069/scrapy-parse-javascript)